# How to avoid strange behaviour in a Rails + jQuery combo using select_tag

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have used rails `select_tag` to retrieve a list of users, like this.

```
- @mandatory_signatures.each do |mandatory_signature|
    .form-group.row.mt-4
      .col-sm-5
        %label Choose #{mandatory_signature.signature_title}
        .centered-vertical
          = select_tag '', options_from_collection_for_select(find_users_with_certificate_for(mandatory_signature), :id, :full_name), { include_blank: "Select User", class: 'form-control select2 find-user-certificate', style: 'width: 100%;' }

      .col-sm-5
        %label Choose Certificate
        .centered-vertical
          = select_tag nil, "", { include_blank: "Select Certificate", class: 'form-control select2 certificate-list', style: 'width: 100%;' }

      .col-sm-2.pl-3
        %label Signature
        .form-control.invisible
        %img.rounded-circle{:src => "http://via.placeholder.com/80x80"}
```

This returns a list of users and on choosing one of the users, I'm suppose to call an API and list out certificates to belong to a user.

Using this jquery function, i'm able to retrieve the list of certificates:

```
$('.find-user-certificate').change(function() {
    let user_id = $(this).val();

    getUserCertificates(user_id);
});

function getUserCertificates(userId) {
  let hostname = window.location.origin;

  $.ajax({
    url: hostname + '/users/' + userId + '/certificates',
    dataType: 'json',
    method: 'get',
    success: function(data) {
      options = '';
      data.forEach(function(object) {
        options += `<option value=${object.id}>${object.name}</option>`;
      });
      $('.certificate-list').empty();
      $('.certificate-list').append(options);
    }
  });
}
```

Problem now is that whenever I try to retrieve certificate for a user, it populates other drop-downs as well as the required dropdown. I've tried using HTML id and class but did not produce the right result.

Here's what it looks like in the screenshot below: 
[image]

What is the right way to do this? Make the User selected in the dropdown only populate the certificate list of the corresponding dropdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define somehow the dropdown for update. `$('.certificate-list')` returns all certificate dropdowns on the page. You can use id of mandatory_signature for this purpose.

```
- @mandatory_signatures.each do |mandatory_signature|
    .form-group.row.mt-4
      .col-sm-5
        %label Choose #{mandatory_signature.signature_title}
        .centered-vertical
          = select_tag '', options_from_collection_for_select(find_users_with_certificate_for(mandatory_signature), :id, :full_name), { include_blank: "Select User", class: 'form-control select2 find-user-certificate', style: 'width: 100%;', data: { mandatory: mandatory_signature.id } }

      .col-sm-5
        %label Choose Certificate
        .centered-vertical
          = select_tag nil, "", { include_blank: "Select Certificate", class: "form-control select2 certificate-list js-#{ mandatory_signature.id }", style: 'width: 100%;' }

$('.find-user-certificate').change(function() {
    let user_id = $(this).val();
    let mandatory_id = $(this).data('mandatory')

    getUserCertificates(user_id, mandatory_id);
});

function getUserCertificates(userId, mandatoryId) {
  let hostname = window.location.origin;

  $.ajax({
    url: hostname + '/users/' + userId + '/certificates',
    dataType: 'json',
    method: 'get',
    success: function(data) {
      options = '';
      data.forEach(function(object) {
        options += `<option value=${object.id}>${object.name}</option>`;
      });
      $('.certificate-list.js-' + mandatoryId).empty();
      $('.certificate-list.js-' + mandatoryId).append(options);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: @mayorsanmayor, happy to help you :)